# Oreo Emulator doesn't have Google Play Services for Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm a newb to Android and Android Studio so I'm doing a Udemy course on it.

The course is now at the point where Android API's are being explored. The Android 8.0.0 Emulator however, does not have Google Play Services, and without Google Play I have no way of installing it... I have followed a couple of tutorials to get play services installed which involves downloading a zip and dragging it to the emulator.

After prompting me to install it just failed each time...

I have created a new Android Studio project with the Google Maps template and created API keys.
When building the app this is the screen I get:
[image: App launched]

Notably clicking update doesn't do anything...

Does anyone know how I can go about using Google Maps API's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AVD supports updating Google Play Services, you should be able to update Play Services from the emulator settings screen:

[image]

If it does not, create a new AVD that indicates it does support updating Google Play Services, and try again. System images that support Google Play have a (Google Play) suffix in the chooser:

[image]