# How to update my location after location turned on in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and I am trying something to achieve in this example, I want to update user location after user turns location on, say for suppose user didn't turn on his location first after we give user a pop up saying this application need location on then it should update data but in the below example its not working, please help me out.

[Here is the example what I am working on](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-example-tab-)

PS:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just subscribe to "onLocationChanged" Stream like in the example.

```
_location.onLocationChanged().listen((Map<String,double> result) {
          var latitude = result["latitude"]; //This is called always when the location updates
          var longitude = result["longitude"];
        });
```

For showing a popup when the user has no location enabled use this:

```
try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation;
} on PlatformException {
await showDialog<dynamic>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("No Location"),
                  content: Text(
                      "Please allow this App to use Location or turn on your GPS."),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "Ok"
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, cause it have own pop up saying that as in image if my mobile location is off, but after I press "ok" location turned on but location is not updating on screen, it still shows null my question is how to update that data. That's what I want to achieve..

Comment: Please try to use an Emulator with Google Play Services installed. How to do this is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135124/oreo-emulator-doesnt-have-google-play-services-for-maps-api. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am using an emulator only, and tried to make that update thing manually by passing some data in AVD still its not working I installed in my mobile and checked by moving one place to another place still not working.
Thanks for your response sir.